# How to close a Mac application by Quit button from the menu bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I have developed a Mac application by using tkinter library in Python. It's closing properly if I close by File--> Close (or) close button on the application but it hangs if I close by Quit option from the menu bar. I just want to call the **on_closing** function to properly close the application but I don't know how to call the function when pressing the Quit button from the menu bar.

```
def on_closing():
            app.destroy()
app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
```

[image: If we close by application name (mediavalet)--> Quit, it's started hanging. To terminate properly we need to call the on_closing method]

I am using Python 3.8 and Mac environment.
Can you please help me out to solve the issue. If we close by application name (mediavalet)--> Quit, it's started hanging. To terminate properly we need to call the on_closing method.

**Update :**

The menu bar in the application is created by MAC by default. We need to close the application when pressing button the quit button that's it.

Comment: `app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)` can be anywhere else in the code except the function, but inside `on_closing()` say `app.destroy()` or `root.destroy()`

Comment: Noted, the fact that you updated the Q with my answer, its not recommended to update the Q with one of the answers.

Comment: I just updated the question, it's syntax mistake

Comment: @T.SURESH Please check the updated answer. If that still doesn't work, you will have to provide us a [MINIMUM REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

What I got from this question is that you have a `Menu` in your app (the one in the image - and you say you did not create that menu ) which has a
`menu item` called `quit` and that should result in app `termination` when clicked.

Try this:

```
import sys

def on_closing():
    app.quit()
    sys.exit()      

app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
```

***Edit***
If the above doesn't work, try creating a new menu item in `file` menu and assign the command to be `on_closing.`

***In a case that doesn't work, you will have to provide us a [MINIMUM REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work with.***

Comment: Please see the above picture you can understand the problem.

Comment: @T.SURESH A) Is that the application you built? B) Are you asking how to implement a menu which will have a button 'quit' allowing you to quit the app when clicked? If yes, I have an easy solution.

Comment: A.) Yes by my team members. B.) Yes, menu is already there we need to close properly

Comment: In that case You may need to share a `minimum reproducible code` (I would prefer only the snippet dealing with menu creation). 

Just a hint that You need to assign the command `on_closing` to the menu item `quit`.

Comment: @T.SURESH  Please Check the edited answer to see if it works for you or not.

Comment: @T.SURESH In that case please `edit` your question to either include the code snippet dealing with Menu Bar and their commands OR provide a `minimum reproducible example`. 'cause there is no other way for us to see what's wrong.